# Moved virtual machine to another drive, how do I specify the new path?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed Oracle virtual box. Using this I have created a virtual machine some time ago. 
Later on, I moved my virtual machine to an external hard drive (to save space because it was 50 gb)

Now I want to use this virtual machine again. However, when I open oracle vm virtualbox manager the status of the virtual machine is marked as "inaccessible". This of course makes sense since I have moved the virtual machine from its original position, but how can I change the setting so my computer know that the virtual box is on my external hard drive?

Thank you so much for your help!

Kind regards 
Ditlev

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the virtual machine and then adding it again (in the menu under "machine/add"?

If nothing else works you can always use a symbolic link.

Comment: What is a symbolic link?

Comment: Symbolic links can be used to move a file or folder somewhere else e.g. to another hard drive and still be able to access it at the old location.  
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/